# How to write a batch function to add tab character?

Tags: batch-file

I have this function to add a new line and I want to modify it to add a tab character not a new line. How can this be done ?

```
@echo off
Echo Hello & Call:SkipLine 4 & echo StackOverflow & Pause
:SkipLine
For /L %%I In (1,1,%1) Do Echo(
```

Comment: Is your desired output `Hello<4xTAB>StackOverflow`?

Comment: @Stephan in general ==> Hello<N*TAB>StackOverflow which N is a number of tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to write a string without linefeed, use `set /p`. Unfortunately leading whitespaces (spaces and TABs) are ignored, so `<nul set /p "=<TAB>"` doesn't work.

This should do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Call:SkipLine 4
echo Hello%x%StackOverflow
Pause
exit /b

:SkipLine
set "x="
For /L %%I In (1,1,%1) Do set "x=!x!    "
REM                                  ^-- this is a TAB
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example like posted by ***Stephan***

Thanks to **Walid**

```
@echo off
Call:MyTab 1
echo Salut [%TAB%] Hello

Call:MyTab 5
echo Hi ! [%TAB%] How are you ?

Call:MyTab 10
echo Hello  [%TAB%] World !
pause
exit /b

:MyTab
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "CHAR="
set "_X9=   "
For /L %%I In (1,1,%1) Do set "CHAR=!CHAR!%_X9%"
(
  endlocal
  set "TAB=%CHAR%"
  exit /b
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
@echo off <br>
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion <br>
set "TAB=   " <<<--- put a tab or blank spaces here <br>
echo Hello!TAB!world <br>
echo bye. sjo. <br>
```